# Get tuple data in an array containing only one element from another tuple

Tags: python

Example: I want to select tuple in an array(t_bet), which contains just one element from `judge_tpl = (5,12,24)`. For example, `(3, 4, 5, 16, 30)` is ok while `(3, 12, 24, 29, 30)` is not because it contains two elements.

```
t_bet = [(3, 12, 24, 29, 30),
 (3, 13, 18, 19, 22),
 (1, 11, 16, 17, 22),
 (3, 4, 5, 16, 30),
 (1, 11, 15, 20, 24)]

lst = []
for i in t_bet:
    if (5 in i) and (12 not in i) and (24 not in i ) :
        lst.append(i)
    elif (5 not in i) and (12 in i) and (24 not in i ):
        lst.append(i)
    elif (5 not in i) and (12 not in i) and (24 in i ):
        lst.append(i)

lst: [(3, 4, 5, 16, 30), (1, 11, 15, 20, 24)]
```

I have to list all combinations using `if..elif`,which is inconvenient especially when there are so many elements in `judge_tpl`.

Notice: The tuples in `t_bet` have same lengths while there are more than 10 elements in  `judge_tpl`.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I have updated but I think the number of tuples and the length do not affect the result.

Comment: `[bet for bet in t_bet if len(set(bet) & set(judge_tpl)) == 1]`

Comment: Do duplicates matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need parenthesis around the conditions in your if statements

   `if x in y and another_x in y` is the same as `if (x in y) and (another_x in y)`
2. Use list comprehensions when possible [see PEP8#202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)
3. Use intersection of sets to get how many elements occur in both tuples

   If duplicated don't matter (as they do not in your code) it is possible to convert the tuples into `sets` and check if the intersection between the sets are `1` (Meaning there is only 1 element that occurs in both) Like [@Maarten Fabré](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/123200/maarten-fabr%C3%A9) suggested

---

```
JUDGE = (5, 12, 24)

def valid_bet(bets):
    return [bet for bet in bets if len(set(bet) & set(JUDGE)) == 1]
    # return [bet for bet in best if len(set(bet).intersection(set(JUDGE))) == 1]
    # set_a & set_b == set_a.intersection(set_b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bets = [(3, 12, 24, 29, 30),
            (3, 13, 18, 19, 22),
            (1, 11, 16, 17, 22),
            (3, 4, 5, 16, 30),
            (1, 11, 15, 20, 24)]
    print(valid_bet(bets))
```